# How can I jump to another loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, python-3.7

I have a problem. I don't know how to jump to another loop. Should I use 'continue' or 'break' in the current loop? (python3.x)

> While True: <-- continue to this
>
> > While True:
> >
> > > > continue <-- continue to the first while loop

Comment: Could you share any code example where you would want this kind of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` key word allows you to exit the presiding loop you are in. So if you have a statement like:

```
while True:
    while True:
         break
```

The break will send you back to the first loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the inner loop to continue the outer loop

```
while True:
    while True:
        # do some checks if you want to
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use break as suggested it exits the inner loop when a condition is met. Consider this example from [here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html][1]

```
for n in range(2, 10):
 for x in range(2, n):
     if n % x == 0:
         print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
         break
 else:
     # loop fell through without finding a factor
     print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

results
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 equals 2 * 2
5 is a prime number
6 equals 2 * 3
7 is a prime number
8 equals 2 * 4
9 equals 3 * 3